# How to replace a get parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page listing articles from a database.  When user clicks a tag label they are taken to a blogsbycategory.php page. This page gets the tag parameter from the url and returns all blogs that have this tag. On the right hand side of this page I have a list of tags.  How do I change the GET so when a user click a tag in the list, the url parameter will update and they can view all blogs for that chosen tag.

http://example.com/articles/blogsbycategory.php?tag=People%20management

```
    <?php 
          $tag = $_GET["tag"];
        
    
        $sql = "select * from blogs where tag = '$tag' " ;
        
        $rs = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        //get row
        $fetchRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
    ?>
```

```
    

  <h3>Tags</h3>
                 <?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
   echo '<li>' .$row["tagName"]. '</li><hr />';
   echo '</ul>';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Just use link with appropriate url.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks.  I thought there may be another way without refreshing the page

Comment: I have added jquery sample (not tested). It would be nice to protect your code from sql injections: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<h3>Tags</h3>
                 <?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
   echo '<li><a href="http://example.com/articles/blogsbycategory.php?tag=' .$row["tagName"]. '">' . $row["tagName"] . '</a></li><hr />';
   echo '</ul>';
  }
  ?>
```

With jQuery something like this:

```
<h3>Tags</h3>
                     <?php 
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          echo '<ul style="list-style: none;">';
       echo '<li onclick="$('#articleContainer').load(' . $row["tagName"] . ')">' . $row["tagName"] . '</li><hr />';
       echo '</ul>';
      }
      ?>
<div id="art" style="width: 600px; height: 800px; border: 1px solid grey;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

List them as links

```
<h3>Tags</h3>
<ul>
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { ?>
    <li><a href="/articles/blogsbycategory.php?tag=<?php echo urlencode($row["tagName"]); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["tagName"]); ?></a></li>
  <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

**And please quote the data before you use them in a SQL statement.**